# UV warp in areas around bevels on cylinders

Tags: uv

I am currently UV unwrapping a set of pipes, which are (or should at least be if I did it properly) evenly sized bent cylinders. But i am getting some warps around the beveled bends.

[image]

Usually unwrapping cylinder-like shapes is just as easy as seaming the caps and then putting on seam along the whole cylinder but it doesn't work here.

I tried changing between conformal and angle based Method for unwrapping but it didn't help.

Putting seams after bevels also helps to an extent but it adds a lot of unnecessary seams.

[image]

How do I make it work better?

[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your object?

Comment: @moonboots blend file has been added